# Erro no mapeamento @OneToMany com JPA and Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

No momento, estou tendo um problema com o mapeamento `@OneToMany`/`@ManyToOne` na minha aplicação. Gostaria que quando eu persistir minha entidade `Sale` automaticamente salva-se os items da venda em único tiro.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sale")
public class Sale implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3857608619547245492L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "company", nullable = false)
    private Long company;


    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "sale", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<SaleItem> saleItems = new ArrayList<>();

    public Sale() {
    }

    public void addSaleItem(SaleItem saleItem) {
       getSaleItems().add(saleItem);
       saleItem.setSale(this);
    }

    //****************************Getters and Setters****************************

}



@Entity
@Table(name = "sale_item")
public class SaleItem implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1016354254590870341L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "company", nullable = false)
    private Long company;    

    @Column(name = "description", nullable = false)
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "amount", nullable = false)
    private Double amount;

    @Column(name = "price", nullable = false)
    private Double price;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Sale sale;

    public SaleItem() {

    }

    //**************************** SEM SALE Getters e Setters ****************************





    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o)
            return true;
        if (!(o instanceof SaleItem))
            return false;
        return id != null && id.equals(((SaleItem) o).getId());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return 31;
    }   

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "SaleItem [id=" + id + ", company=" + company + ", product=" + product + ", created=" + created
                + ", updated=" + updated + ", description=" + description + ", amount=" + amount + ", price=" + price
                + ", discount=" + discount + ", user=" + user + ", unit=" + unit + ", sale=" + sale + "]";
    }


}

    //*********************** My Controller ***********************

    /**
     * Create Sale
     * 
     * @param sale
     * @param result
     * @return ResponseEntity<Response<SaleDto>>
     * @throws ParseException
     */
    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Response<SaleDto>> create(@Valid @RequestBody SaleDto saleDto, BindingResult result)
            throws ParseException {

        log.info("Creating sale: {}", saleDto.toString());
        Response<SaleDto> response = new Response<SaleDto>();

        validateSale(saleDto, result);

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            log.error("Error - invalid information for Sale: {}", result.getAllErrors());
            result.getAllErrors().forEach(error -> response.getErrors().add(error.getDefaultMessage()));
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(response);
        }

        response.setData(this.convertSaleDto(this.nova(saleDto, result)));
        return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
    }

    private Sale nova(SaleDto saleDto, BindingResult result) throws ParseException {

       Sale sale = new Sale();
       sale.setCompany(saleDto.getCompany());
       sale.setUser(saleDto.getUser());
       sale.setType(TypeSales.valueOf(saleDto.getType()));
       sale.setDescription(saleDto.getDescription());
       sale.setValue(saleDto.getValue());
       sale.setSubValue(saleDto.getSubValue());
       sale.setDiscount(saleDto.getDiscount());


       for (int i = 0; i < saleDto.getItems().size(); i++) {
           SaleItem saleItem = new SaleItem();
           saleItem.setCompany(saleDto.getCompany());
           saleItem.setUser(saleDto.getUser());
           saleItem.setProduct(saleDto.getItems().get(i).getProduct());
           saleItem.setAmount(saleDto.getItems().get(i).getAmount());
           saleItem.setPrice(saleDto.getItems().get(i).getPrice());
           saleItem.setDescription(saleDto.getItems().get(i).getDescription());
           saleItem.setDiscount(saleDto.getItems().get(i).getDiscount());
           saleItem.setUnit(saleDto.getItems().get(i).getUnit());
           sale.addSaleItem(saleItem);
       }

       return this.saleService.persist(sale);
    }



    //**************************My Service**************

    /**
     * Persist a sale
     * 
     * @param Sale
     * @return Sale
     */
    Sale persist(Sale sale);



//******************My impl***********************
@Transactional
public Sale persist(Sale sale) {
    log.info("Persisting sale {}", sale);
    return this.saleRepository.save(sale);
}
```

O problema que apenas está salvando a entidade `Sale` deixando em branco sempre os itens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando o relacionamento é bidirecional, você deve ligar os dois lados da relação **explicitamente**:

```
private Sale nova(SaleDto saleDto, BindingResult result) throws ParseException {
    SaleItem saleItem = new SaleItem();
    saleItem.setCompany(saleDto.getCompany());
    saleItem.setPrice(saleDto.getItems().get(0).getPrice());
    saleItem.setDescription(saleDto.getItems().get(0).getDescription());
    saleItem.setUnit(saleDto.getItems().get(0).getUnit());

    Sale sale = new Sale();
    sale.setCompany(saleDto.getCompany());
    sale.setUser(saleDto.getUser());
    sale.addSaleItem(saleItem);
    saleItem.setSale(sale);   // <-- Isso é muito importante de se fazer.

    return this.saleService.persist(sale);
}
```

Comment: Então a sua sugestão funcionou após eu utilizar o @JsonIgnore na entidade Sale o que eu não faço ideia porque só funcionou se eu utilizar essa anotação.
Atualizei o meu código caso queira analisar.

Comment: Você resolveu com o @ jsonignore o que é chamado de circular reference que acontece quando um objeto se refere a outro e esse outro por sua vez se refere ao primeiro. Um erro muito comum em relacionamentos bidirecionais. As anotações @ JsonManagedReference e @ JsonBackReference são uma opção pra resolver isso também.

Comment: @mPissolato Usar a mesma classe para fazer mapeamento objeto-relacional e gerar JSON é má ideia. Já trabalhei num sistema assim e dava muita dor-de-cabeça. O motivo é que há muitos casos onde a estrutura do JSON não deveria ser a mesma que a do banco. Exemplos: acrescentar campos calculados no JSON que não estão no banco de dados; estruturas no JSON que refletem o resultado de relatórios gerado a partir de diversas tabelas com uma consulta complexa; não colocar senhas no JSON; não colocar dados de entidades relacionadas que sejam desnecessárias para alguma determinada funcionalidade; etc.

Comment: @mPissolato E então a solução é você ter um conjunto de classes para fazer o mapeamento objeto-relacional, e deixa o Hibernate/JPA lidar com ele e um outro conjunto de classes diferente só para gerar o JSON e alguns métodos em ambas as classes para converter de um para outro, lembrando que nem sempre essa conversão é uma relação de 1-para-1. Aliás, você já está fazendo isso em alguns lugares ao ter um `SaleDto`.

Comment: @VictorStafusa! Sim eu concordo com você eu vou utilizar DTO para tratar a entrada como a saída fazendo conversões. Eu sempre fiz o processo de persistência usando JEE porem estou tentando melhorar minhas skils com spring e usando o repository crud do para persistir master/detail está sendo complicado.

Answer (score 2):

Nesse caso você pode usar um relacionamento unidirecional:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sale")
public class Sale implements Serializable {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Long id;

   @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
   @JoinColumn(name = "sale_id")
   private List<SaleItem> saleItems = new ArrayList<>();

   public List<SaleItem> getSaleItems() {
        return saleItems;
   }


}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sale_item")
public class SaleItem implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

   // deve remover a classe Sale desse lado
}
```

Para inserir um item você pode usar, por exemplo:

```
public void addSaleItem(SaleItem saleItem) {
   getSaleItems().add(item);
}
```

> http://blog.triadworks.com.br/jpa-por-que-voce-deveria-evitar-relacionamento-bidirecional

Comment: Então utilizando essa sua sugestão eu acabo tendo o erro que não foi preenchido o sale_id.

2020-02-09 00:50:55.734 ERROR 17036 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Field 'sale_id' doesn't have a default value

Comment: Vc manteve o atributo id nas classes ? Os ids estão sendo auto incrementados ?

Comment: Mantive os ID's porem tirei a classe Sale de entidade item.

Comment: A propriedade mapped by tbm foi removida?

Comment: Sim, removi a unica duvida que fiquei se devo declarar na entidade SaleItem o "sale_id" ?

Comment: Não precisa. Pode ser que suas mudanças não estejam sendo refletidas no banco e pode demandar a recriação do banco. Se ainda fizer sentido pra vc de uma olhada nesse link, ele tem um problema bem parecido com o seu e foi assim que ele o resolveu https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804514/hibernate-field-id-doesnt-have-a-default-value

Comment: Faz sentido o mapeamento unidirecional o que não faz sentido que em momento algum eu identifico para os itens quem é o pai. Eu acabei de ler o artigo vc me indicou e foi realizado a identificação do pai nos itens.

Comment: No artigo indicado na resposta, ele exemplifica em cima de um bidirecional, promovendo algumas melhoras. No caso do unidirecional algo como esse deveria funcionar pra você: https://reinaldoc.wordpress.com/2011/11/25/jpa-onetomany-unidirecional-com-joincolumn/